# Python script goes to website but doesn't click button intended to

Tags: python

As a test, I am trying to create a script that goes to my website and clicks on the learn more button, but am having trouble actually automatically clicking the button.

I've tried everything that I've found on stack overflow but nothing has worked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
import time

url = 'https://www.mwstan.com'
driver = webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('learnmore')
element.click()
```

Comment: 1. I get an error when running your code
2. I think that's not how you use driver? search for something like "selenium driver" or "chrome driver"?

Comment: you need to assign `driver` to a web-browser instance such as e.g. `driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chrome_driver)` or whichever selenium webdriver you have.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to install a binary for whatever driver you are going to use

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"

def get_url_example(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
    driver.get(url)
    button = driver.find_element_by_id("learnmore")
    button.click()
    # you can access the page source here using driver.page_source

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_url_page_source("https://www.mwstan.com")
```

This code works for me and hits your button.

This is using chrome webdriver but you can use another webdriver. JUst makesure you move the driver and access the path correctly like in line

```
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
```